# error can not Convert CommandParameter object to String

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I currently have a WPF data grid with a button.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AVL3DataGrid" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AVL3DB}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.802,-5.399" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,36,0,0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Name="LaunchAVL3URLButton" Click="LaunchAVL3URLButton_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=AVL3URL}">Launch</Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

When i click the button I want it to take the URL and pass it into a web browsers, but I don't know how to convert the object to a string.

```
private void LaunchAVL3URLButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object AVL3URL = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter;

            string url = AVL3URL;
            string browserPath = GetStandardBrowserPath();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(browserPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No default browser found!");
            }
            else
            {
                Process.Start(browserPath, url);
            }
        }
```

I get the following error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set an object to a string here:

```
 string url = AVL3URL;
```

This should be:

```
string url = (string)AVL3URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your object to String explicitly.

Instead of  `string url = AVL3URL;`

do  `string url = Convert.ToString(AVL3URL);`

Answer (score 0):

Object doesn't not implicitly cast to string.

```
string AVL3URL = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter.toString();
```